# Login with twitter in android studio using Fragment activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

I have not found any tutorials or links for login with twitter in the android studio. Please give me any reference to for the twitter login using the fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Integrate [Fabric](http://fabric.io) in your Android Studio and twitter kit which will help you login via Twitter in your app

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the below sample and tutorial link :

https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/twitter-login-android-tutorial-integrating-twitter-login/